# Using DataAnnotations with Regular Expressions to not Match

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, entity-framework, data-annotations

Is it possible with [DataAnnotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)s and regular expressions to *filter* an entry in the text box ? i.e. To trigger an invalid response when the word "apt" is in the string ?

Comment: Do you want to invalidate the TextBox or what ? What do you mean by filter exactly, a sample input and output would be great.

Comment: Yes I would like to invalidate the text box if it contains certain abbreviations as detected by the RegEx

Comment: What language or platform are you using ?

Comment: Sorry.. C#/Microsoft stack

Comment: I am sorry, although I read about ASP.NET-MVC but I am working with it but I still think it is still possible but you will have to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that using negative look-arounds, like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?!apt).)*$", ErrorMessage = "You can not have that")]
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a good reference question for these types of regular expressions.

[Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)